# How can I split a string while preserving parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I'm splitting strings to generate keys for a dictionary but I'm having trouble with parentheses.

I'd like to take the string **contemporary building(s) (2000 c.e. to present)** and split it into three keys: `contemporary`, `building(s)`, and `(2000 c.e. to present)`

Up to now, I've been using `re.findall('\w+', key)`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use also `re.findall('[(][^)]*[)]|\S+', key)`, if you do not have parentheses within parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do this with a regex. You could definitely do it with a parser. Both of those are pretty complex, though, so unless you need more power and generality why not just merge the pieces from `re.findall('\w+', key)` back together?

```
parts = re.findall('[\w)(\.]+', key)
[parts[0], parts[1], parts[2] + " " + parts[3] + " " + parts[4] + " " + parts[5]]
```

More generally you could loop over the parts counting the number of open and close parentheses. Keep a counter which increments for every open paren and decrements for every close paren. Every time the counter goes from 0 to 1 start concatenating parts and stop when it hits 0 again.

These simple solutions depend on your strings being fairly simple and well-behaved, but all solutions will to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should do the trick using `re.findall`:

```
(?:\w+(?:\(\w+\))?)|(?:\([\w\ \.]+\)))
```

The first group `(?:\w+(?:\(\w+\))?)` matches a series of word characters followed by an optional series of word characters inside parentheses.

```
\w+ - word character one or more times
\(\w+\)? - (optional) opening parenthesis, word character one or more times,
           closing parenthesis
```

The second group `(?:\([\w\ \.]+\)))` matches any word characters, spaces or periods wrapped in parentheses.

```
\([\w\ \.]+\) - opening partnthesis, (either a word character,
                space or period one or more times), closing parenthesis
```

The `?:` at the start of each group just-means to not capture it, so `.findall` only returns the matches you want.

This is only really guaranteed to work on the example you provided or something quite similar and could do with some extra consideration if there's going to be a lot more variance in the input, but it's a start.